# Character Class \w not Working?

Tags: regex, node.js

I'm doing the following regular expression in Node:

```
 var checkPath   = '^\/path\/([\w]+)\/messages$';
 var path    = '/path/54946fde030ba8cc5471efc9/messages';
 var match   = path.match(checkPath);
```

This doesn't seem to work.

However, when I do this:

```
 var checkPath   = '^\/path\/([0-9a-z]+)\/messages$';
 var path    = '/path/54946fde030ba8cc5471efc9/messages';
 var match   = path.match(checkPath);
```

It seems to work.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to write like

```
var checkPath   = '^/path/(\\w+)/messages$';
var path    = '/path/54946fde030ba8cc5471efc9/messages';
var match   = path.match(checkPath);
```

**Changes made**

- Escape `\w` as `\\w`
- `\w` => `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` hence enclosing  `\w` in another class does not add any advantage, written simply as `\w`

Comment: You would need to escape the other backslashes, too (`\/` -> `\\/`).  Better yet, just drop those backslashes; `/` doesn't need escaping when you create the regex in the form of a string literal